# Where can I find the reference for the spring-data-elasticsearch configuration properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Across the web, I can see that `spring-data-elasticsearch` has some configuration properties that you can define in your `application.properties`, such as:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch

elasticsearch.index.name=my_index
elasticsearch.user.type=user
```

However, in IntelliJ, I can see that, for example:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
```

... are actually now deprecated. However, I can't seem to find anything in the `spring-data-elasticsearch` documentations that either lists what the available properies are, or, what the deprecated ones should be replaced with instead.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) may help.

Answer (score 7):

Those properties are from `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`, not from `spring-data-elasticsearch`.

As @code_mechanic suggested, in [Spring Boot Reference Documentation > Common Application properties > Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-data) you will find the properties available for the *current* version of Spring Boot. Here some of the properties related to Elasticsearch:

> | Key | Default Value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.connection-timeout |  | Connection timeout. |
> | spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.endpoints |  | Comma-separated list of the Elasticsearch endpoints to connect to. |
> | spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.max-in-memory-size |  | Limit on the number of bytes that can be buffered whenever the input stream needs to be aggregated. |
> | spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.password |  | Credentials password. |
> | spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.socket-timeout |  | Read and Write Socket timeout. |
> | spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.use-ssl | `false` | Whether the client should use SSL to connect to the endpoints. |
> | spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.username |  | Credentials username. |
> | spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled | `true` | Whether to enable Elasticsearch repositories. |
> | spring.elasticsearch.rest.connection-timeout | `1s` | Connection timeout. |
> | spring.elasticsearch.rest.password |  | Credentials password. |
> | spring.elasticsearch.rest.read-timeout | `30s` | Read timeout. |
> | spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris | `[http://localhost:9200]` | Comma-separated list of the Elasticsearch instances to use. |
> | spring.elasticsearch.rest.username |  | Credentials username. |

The reference documentation of previous versions of Spring Boot can be found in https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn.

You might also be interested in [Spring Boot Docs > Spring Boot Features >
Working With Nosql Technologies > Elasticsearch](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-boot-docs/boot-features/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-elasticsearch), which describes how to connect using REST clients and reactive REST clients, the dependencies you need and the configuration properties.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Spring docs for Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference) :

> The `TransportClient` is deprecated as of **Elasticsearch 7** and will be
> removed in **Elasticsearch 8**. Spring Data Elasticsearch will support the
> `TransportClient` as long as it is available in the used Elasticsearch
> version but has deprecated the classes using it since version `4.0`

**Note:** *This would mean that Spring team would also deprecate the legacy properties supported for Elasticsearch 7.*

Now, Spring team recommends the developers to use `RestHighLevelClient` which is now the default client of `Elasticsearch`. It is a direct replacement for the `TransportClient` as it accepts and returns the same request/response objects.

Code to demonstrate given below :

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

       ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()  
            .connectedTo("localhost:9300")
            .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();                         
    }
}
```

The above configuration needs to be created by overriding the default bean. Moreover, you don't need to provide cluster name explicitly. It will automatically find it.

Read above linked documentation for reference as it has all the necessary information.

- Refer to this as well : [Elastic Search Java High Level REST Client Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_changing_the_client_8217_s_initialization_code.html)